# Dart: how many string objects are allocated when using the * operator in an assignment?

Tags: string, memory, dart

In the following code, I would expect 3 total string allocations to be made:

```dart
String str  = "abc";
String str2 = str*2; //"abcabc"
```

- 1 when creating `str`
- another when creating a copy of str to concatenate with itself
- a third to hold the concatenation of str with itself (`str2`)

Are there fewer or more allocations made in this example? I know that strings are immutable in Dart but I'm unsure how these operations work under the hood because of this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no knowledge about the inner workings of the Dart VM but I would say:

`"abc"` creates one String object.
`String str = "abc";` makes `str` reference the one created String object (`"abc"`).
`str*2;` creates a second String object "abcabc" which `str2` refers to after the second statement.

All in all two String objects.

Comment: Correct. If you look at `"str" * 4`, the VM only allocates one extra string for the result. The dart2js compiled code actually does create intermediate strings, but JavaScript engines are optimized for that case.

Answer (score 2):

With optimising compilers it's difficult to know for sure. If you want to know more you can look at the generated native code with [irhydra](http://mrale.ph/blog/2013/02/17/release-the-irhydra.html).

In general a good approach is write code to be as readable as possible, and then use tools to find the bottle necks in your code, and optimise those.

For example [observatory](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/observatory/) can show you which objects are using up the most memory, and which methods are running the most.